# Failed_when module with OR

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to handle errors in my playbook, precisely, I want to be able to ignore a specific error. The message that I want to "accept" is contains the phrase "already exists". In order to get that to work, I need an OR statement, as I also want to accept successful task execution.

```
[...]
register: command_result
failed_when: not ("already exists" in command_result.msg or "CALL" in command_result.statusmessage)
```

The problem is, the task is accepted when the error message consists "already exists", as I wished, however, "CALL" in statusmessage is not working - meaning the task fails even if the statusmessage is exactly that. There must be something wrong with my or statement. I've tried:

```
"'already exists' in command_result.msg or 'CALL' in command_result.statusmessage"
```

But that does not work as well.

What is important: when a task returns an error, command_result.statusmessage is empty - `"command_result.statusmessage": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'statusmessage'"`. Could it be the reason for the following error?

> "The conditional check '('already exists' not in command_result.msg)
>   or ('CALL' in command_result.statusmessage)' failed. The error was:
>   error while evaluating conditional (('already exists' not in
>   command_result.msg) or ('CALL' in command_result.statusmessage)):
>   Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string

I was hoping that it just parses the string "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!". How can I resolve my issue then?

Comment: Please see the following part of the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"command_result.statusmessage": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'statusmessage'"*

A: By default put an empty string to the attribute `statusmessage`. For example

```yaml
      failed_when: not (('already exists' in command_result.msg) or
                        ('CALL' in command_result.statusmessage|default('')))
```